# cocos2d-x 3.1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Touch event + function

Tags: cocos2d-x, exc-bad-access, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm cocos2d-x beginner and having trouble with TouchBegan event + function.
I always get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the *[label->setString("Foo Bar");]* point when I run this simple code with xCode(5.1.1 + iPhone sim 7.1).

I tried a few ways to solve, but I'm completely stuck up in this problem for 2 or 3 days.

Does anyone have any idea for the wrong point?

***HelloWorld.h***

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::LayerGradient
{
    public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    virtual bool init();

    bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event);


    cocos2d::Label* label;
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

***HelloWorld.cpp***

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}


bool HelloWorld::init()
{

    if(!LayerGradient::initWithColor(Color4B(0, 0, 0, 255), Color4B(50, 50, 50, 255))){
        return false;
    }
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();



    auto label = Label::create("Hello World", "Arial", 112);
        label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));
    this->addChild(label, 1);



    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchBegan, this);
    this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 100);

    return true;
}



bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event){
    label->setString("Foo Bar");
    return true;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line :

```
auto label = Label::create("Hello World", "Arial", 112);
```

In this line you declare a new variable named `label` whose scope is only for the `init` function. You also have a class variable also named `label` and they're not the same. If you declare a variable in a method with the same name as a class variable, it will `shadow` it. Consider this example :

```
class A {
    int variable;

    void method() {

        int variable; // this is not the same thing as the one above

        variable = 5; //assignment to local variable

        this->variable = 3; //asignment to class variable

    }
}
```

So you actually don't assign anything to your class variable `label` which you later reference in the touch method. The easiest way to solve this would be to remove the `auto` keyword at `auto label` from your `init()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Losiowaty. I think I half-understand what you wrote. I tried removing 'auto' and I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS at 'label->setPosition' line.. mmm...

Comment: Finally, it worked as you said. I've been trying with `Label::createWithTTF` and some reason it returns me EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. But _"`auto` deleted ver"_ worked completely with `Label::create`. Thank you so so much for you suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Losiowaty, the use of `auto` can be dangerous sometimes.

```
cocos2d::Label* label = cocos2d::Label::create("Hello World", "Arial", 112);
```

Also, there might be a better constructor to use: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.1rc0/db/de4/classcocos2d_1_1_label.html

Comment: This wouldn't solve his problem - it would still not assign the value (address) to the class variable, but rather to the local one.

Comment: Thank you GameDeveloper, I tried this code as well, but as said by Losiowaty, it didn't work. Thanks anyway!